# .htaccess won't rewrite all urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a challenge for you.

Consider these urls:

```
http://mydomain.com/Obj
http://mydomain.com/Obj/index.php
http://mydomain.com/Obj/Mainv2/url.php
http://mydomain.com/Obj/Main/Bids/index.php

 RewriteRule ^Obj/$ Obj/Masterpage/Backoffice.php?Folder=&Page=index.php [NC,S=2,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^Obj/(.*)/(.*)/(.*).php$ Obj/Masterpage/$1.php?Folder=$2&Page=$3.php [NC,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^Obj/(.*)/(.*).php$ Obj/Masterpage/Backoffice.php?Folder=&Page=$2.php [NC,QSA]
```

Now all urls should be work with the htaccess, but I can't get the /Obj/Mainv2/url.php and /Obj/Main/Bids/index.php to work. Only one of the 2 is working.

So to recap:

```
http://mydomain/Obj should result in http://mydomain.com/Masterpage/Backoffice.php?Folder=&Page=index.php

http://mydomain.com/Obj/index.php should also result in http://mydomain.com/Masterpage/Backoffice.php?Folder=&Page=index.php

http://mydomain.com/Obj/Mainv2/url.php should result in http://mydomain.com/Obj/Masterpage/Backoffice.php?Folder=&Page=url.php

http://mydomain.com/Obj/Main/Bids/index.php should result in http://mydomain.com/Obj/Masterpage/Main.php?Folder=Bids&Page=index.php
```

Comment: And how is this **NOT** working?

Comment: Try putting the 3rd rule 2nd.

Comment: @BigChris If I do that the last url is using the wrong redirect. (http://mydomain.com/Obj/Masterpage/Backoffice.php?Folder=&Page=index.php)

Comment: This is the unfortunate situation that your site's logic is using... You may need to look into a RewriteCond to do some further checking as to what URL pattern is seen

Comment: And how do I use the RewriteCond in combination with my problem? (I'm very new to htaccess)

Comment: Do all your URLs have the same "Obj", "Main", "Mainv2" structure, or could there be more "subfolder" names?

Comment: I have just noticed your last RewriteRule is missing a paramter: `RewriteRule ^Obj/(.*)/(.*).php$ Obj/Masterpage/Backoffice.php?Folder=&Page=$2.php [NC,QSA]` - by "Folder="

Comment: Obj is always present. Main en Mainv2 is variable. When Main is added there is always one more subfolder (Bids) and one php file after that. So that is the structure. So you have 2 or 1 subfolder max after Obj.

Comment: And the last rewrite rule should have an empty folder parameter. So that's not a problem. ;-)

Comment: Could you change your RewriteRules to stipulate what to do when "Obj/Main/" or "Obj/Mainv2" are present, rather than try to catch all?

Comment: E.g. `RewriteRule ^Obj/(.*)/(.*)/(.*).php$ Obj/Masterpage/$1.php?Folder=$2&Page=$3.php [NC,QSA]` turned into: `RewriteRule ^Obj/Main/(.*)/(.*).php$ Obj/Masterpage/Main.php?Folder=$1&Page=$2.php [NC,QSA]`

Comment: and: `RewriteRule ^Obj/Mainv2/(.*).php$ Obj/Masterpage/Backoffice.php?Folder=&Page=$1.php [NC,QSA]`

Comment: I'm afraid that is a no go.. Main and Mainv2 are dynamic. They lead or to Backoffice.php or a other file (like Main.php). And I would like to keep that dynamic

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem, but I don't know how to solve it.

The problem is that your 2rd rule is rewritten and its catched by the 3rd rule and will be rerewritten.

so `Obj/Main/Bids/index.php` results in `Obj/Masterpage/Main.php?Folder=Bids&Page=index.php` but that will also go through the htaccess file and it will rewrite it as `Obj/Masterpage/Backoffice.php?Folder=&Page=index.php` because it has a match.